# Function returning object instead of Array, unable to .Map

Tags: javascript

I'm parsing an order feed to identify duplicate items bought and group them with a quantity for upload. However, when I try to map the resulting array, it's showing [object Object], which makes me think something's converting the return into an object rather than an array.

The function is as follows:

```
function compressedOrder (original) {
    var compressed = [];
    // make a copy of the input array

  // first loop goes over every element
    for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {

        var myCount = 1;    
        var a = new Object();
        // loop over every element in the copy and see if it's the same
        for (var w = i+1; w < original.length; w++) {
          if (original[w] && original[i]) {
            if (original[i].sku == original[w].sku) {
        // increase amount of times duplicate is found
                myCount++;
                delete original[w];
            }
          }
        }
          if (original[i]) {
                a.sku = original[i].sku;
                a.price = original[i].price;
                a.qtty = myCount;
                compressed.push(a);
          }
    }
    return compressed;
}
```

And the JS code calling that function is:

```
contents: compressedOrder(item.lineItems).map(indiv => ({
      "id": indiv.sku,
      "price": indiv.price,
      "quantity": indiv.qtty
    }))
```

The result is:

contents: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]

When I JSON.stringify() the output, I can see that it's pulling the correct info from the function, but I can't figure out how to get the calling function to pull it as an array that can then be mapped rather than as an object.

The correct output, which sits within a much larger feed that gets uploaded, should look like this:

> contents:
> [{"id":"sku1","price":17.50,"quantity":2},{"id":"sku2","price":27.30,"quantity":3}]

{It's probably something dead simple and obvious, but I've been breaking my head over this (much larger) programme till 4am this morning, so my head's probably not in the right place}

Comment: The array isn't being converted into an object, but you're pushing objects **into** it. `a = new Object()` ... `compressed.push(a)`.

Comment: Can you provide any codesandbox link ?

Comment: @Mitya you're right. I should change that to a = []. but I'm guessing I can't use .push then.... what's the best way to add nested array elements in there?

Comment: `compressOrder()` returns an array of objects. You then `.map()` them into another array of objects. So what's the actual problem?

Comment: _"it's showing [object Object]"_ - That's only the case when you call `.toString()` on the objects (or implicit through `.join()` on the array). _"contents: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]"_ is how the console of your browser "prints" the array of objects.

Comment: @Andreas I need the output to be the actual contents of the arrays, not the objects. In other words, the output should be more like contents: [{"id":"sku1","price":17.50,"quantity":2]

Comment: did you try `compressed.push(JSON.parse(a))` ?

Comment: You can "output" them like you want. But the question is where? And why? Should they be "printed" in the DOM for the user? Do you want to submit them to a backend/server?

Comment: This is part of an upload that goes to an order-tracking system. So I just want to be able to have the end result of this bit formatted like "contents": [{"id":"sku1","price":17.50,"quantity":2},{"id":"sku2","price":27.30,"quantity":3}]. I'm not quite getting that

Comment: @bakar_dev that gives an error "Unexpected end of JSON input" - understandably, because that's not quite what we want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code was correct all along, but I was running into a limitation of the console itself. I was able to verify this by simply working with the hard-coded values, and then querying the nested array separately.

Thanks anyway for your help and input everyone.

Answer (score -1):

```
contents: compressedOrder(item.lineItems).map(indiv => ({
      "id": indiv.sku,
      "price": indiv.price,
      "quantity": indiv.qtty
    }))
```

In the code above the compressedOrder fucntion returns an array of objects where each object has sku, price and qtty attribute.
Further you are using a map on this array and returning an object again which has attributes id, price and quantity.

What do you expect from this.

Comment: I need the output to instead be like "contents": [{"id":"sku1","price":17.50,"quantity":2},{"id":"sku2","price":27.30,"quantity":3}]

Comment: As per the code you wrote above, this is the expected output which are posting in comment. It should never print contents: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] as there is nothing DDA here

Comment: The point is i want it to show the contents... what needs to be changed in the code to do so?

Comment: This is a javascript array of objects, If you want to display it outside the javascript i.e in HTML or some other language then in that case you will need to stringify that object using JSON.strinigify(contents) and then use that stringified string as display

Comment: That comes close, but the output needs to be an array rather than a string.

Comment: Okay, first of all Where do you want to display it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what exactly solution you need but I've read your question and the comments, It looks like you need array of arrays as response.

So If I've understood your requirement correctly and you could use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#pairs) then following piece of code might help you:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const resp = [{key1:"value1"}, {key2:"value2"}].map(t => _.pairs(t));
console.log(resp);
```

P.S. It is assumed that `compressedOrder` response looks like array of objects.

Comment: Yes, the response current is contents: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
Whereas I need it to be in the format contents: [{"id":"sku1","price":17.50,"quantity":2},{"id":"sku2","price":27.30,"quantity":3}]

Comment: Why down vote? I clearly mentioned assumptions and had chat with OP as well there he affirmed that my assumptions are correct but commented differently here, quite strange!

Comment: Your assumptions were correct, but your solution was not. Lodash is not needed actually, as you'll see from my answer. The problem turned out not to be with the code but with the system I was using to check the code, which wasn't parsing the nested array within the function. When I checked it live, it worked.

Comment: no worries btw I did confirm on private chat that what actually you need and then posted answer :) well good luck